# Mysql transpose complex sql query table dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, transpose

I have a table with two columns, following is the schema:

```
create table scan( `application_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `defect_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL);
```

And the data is populated accordingly. The table stores data for "Application" and its corresponding "Defect Type". I want to perform following 2 actions on this table:

1. Get the Top 3 "Defect Type" of a particular application in terms of percent.
2. Transpose the output from above where the values in "Defect Type" (defect_type) become the columns and its corresponding percent (finalPercent) as the its value.

I am able to achieve 1, following is the SQL Fiddle:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f7b22/5)

However, I am not able to transpose the output as per the requirement. Ideally there should be a single row as follows after both 1 & 2 together:

```
application_name | CrossSide |  CSS  |  XML 
       A         |   33.33   | 33.33 | 16.67
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a dynamic pivot query with `group_concat` and then execute it:

```
set @sql = null;

set @total = (select count(*) as totalcount from scan where application_name = "a");

select group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'round(((count(case when defect_type = ''',
      defect_type,
      ''' then application_name end)/ @total ) * 100 ), 2) as `',
      defect_type, '`'
    )
  ) into @sql 
from ( select  defect_type 
        from   scan 
        where  application_name = "a" 
        group  by defect_type
        order by count(defect_type) desc
        limit 3) t;

set @sql = concat(
'select application_name, ', @sql,
' from scan
where application_name = "a" 
group by application_name'
);

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f7b22/53)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way not to hardcode "CrossSide", "CSS", "XML" and have the column values populate dynamically? These values can be any type of defect and I just wanted Top3 defect_type.

Comment: Awesome. This works perfect for my scenarios and I understand the complexity of it.